# Generate random records for datetime columns by stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate 5 random records from a field which is a `datetime` column and contains several records of (OrderDate) for a given date range using stored procedure for the table named `Orders`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL,
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderDate = DATEADD(......)  
    FROM Orders
END
```

May I get some help!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop works ok for this purpose, especially if you're concerned with limiting your randomness to a bounded date range.
The downside is that potentially many insert queries get executed vs. a single insert for a recursive CTE as in the other answer.

```
create procedure dbo.spGenDates2
@MinDate datetime,
@MaxDate datetime,
@RecordCount int = 5
as
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Range int, @DayOffset int, @Cnt int

SET @Range = DATEDIFF(dd, @MinDate, @MaxDate)
SET @Cnt = 1
WHILE @Cnt <= @RecordCount
BEGIN
    SET @DayOffset = RAND() * (@Range + 1)
    INSERT INTO _test (Dt) VALUES(DATEADD(dd, @DayOffset, @MinDate))
    SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to retrieve data i.e. select 5 random date from the OrderDate column of the Order table for the Max and Min date range. Sorry for the wrong wording in my query.

Comment: that's a much simpler problem - I'll add another answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your syntax I'm assuming you're using SQL Server...

Note that you cannot reliably use the sql random number generator function RAND() within the context of a single query because it does not get reseeded per row so you end up receiving the same, single random number for each row result.  Instead, an approach using NEWID() converted into a numeric does the trick when generating random values within the execution of a single query.

Here's a procedure that will give you n number of sample dates in the near past.

```
create procedure dbo.spGenDates
@MaxDate datetime,
@RecordCount int = 5
as

WITH dates as (
    SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * -1, @MaxDate) D,
        1 as Cnt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * -1, @MaxDate) D,
        x.Cnt + 1 as Cnt
    FROM dates x
    WHERE x.Cnt < @RecordCount
)
INSERT INTO _test (Dt)
SELECT D
FROM dates
```

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question has been clarified (see comments on another answer) to be a desire to SELECT 5 random sample dates within a bounded range from a table.

A query like this will yield the desired result.

```
SELECT TOP (5) OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate >= @StartDate 
  AND OrderDate < @EndDate
ORDER BY NEWID()
```